# Extract JSON object

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
[
"{'_filled': False,\n 'affiliation': u'Postdoctoral Scholar, University of California, Berkeley',\n 'citedby': 113,\n 'email': u'@berkeley.edu',\n 'id': u'4bahYMkAAAAJ',\n 'interests': [u'3D Shape',\n               u'Shape from Texture',\n               u'Shape from Shading',\n               u'Naive Physics',\n               u'Haptics'],\n 'name': u'Steven A. Cholewiak',\n 'url_citations': u'/citations?user=4bahYMkAAAAJ&hl=en',\n 'url_picture': u'/citations?view_op=view_photo&user=4bahYMkAAAAJ&citpid=1'}",
"\n"]
```

I am using python to extract the value of citedby. However, I am not able to figure.
Here is my code:

```
import json
json_data = open("output.json")

data = json.load(json_data)
print data[]
```

Now I know data would take an integer value whereas I would want to have it as a dictionary where in I could search using the key.
Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: yes..I created it

Comment: Actually Its a valid JSON.. I tried to take a snippet of it. Let me edit it properly

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import ast
json_data = open("output.json")

data = json.load(json_data)
print ast.literal_eval(data[0])['citedby']
```

Comment: Glad to help :)